# view.zoom is rendering slow for large canvas size in paper.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

I am using a canvas of 5000 * 20000 size which is very large.

When I am using view.zoom on this canvas then it is rendering bit slow compare to small canvas.

How can I resolve this problem. ?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need such a big canvas? Your should keep your canvas size as small as possible, as it has a lot of impact on performance ( big memory consumptiona and big rendering times ). If you need that resolution you could make a smaller canvas and then scale it using css (image quality will get worse), for example making a 1000 x 4000 canvas and scale x5 using css.
Anyway, best practices are draw only what you need in the smallest canvas possible.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I want to make a infinite scrollable canvas so that i can add more things on canvas. therefore i took a large canvas for now. If you can suggest alternate for this, then it will be helpful to me.

Comment: Render engines have a definition of a scene and only paint the things that are in view. That you have an infinite scrollable scene, doesn't mean that you have to paint it all. You could have a defined 'viewport' of the size of your screen and move that viewport translating all your scene objects (if your view is in 1000, 5000, translate all objects -1000, -5000), and before painting any object, find out if it intersects your viewport.

Comment: I agree but suppose i scale canvas by 0.5 factor and if i will render only those items which are in view then if i will scroll down then items that were not in view they will not be scaled and scaling uniformity will be spoiled.

Comment: In your case, scale the canvas might not be the best solution, as you should also have to scale down all your objects to fit i ( this is an extra  op to canvas, but the canvas size is also much smaller) I would try first the draw-only-visible solution, and if its not enough, try to scale the canvas